# Reversing a file line-wise and character-wise

Tags: bash, shell-builtin, tac

Input:

```
hello
enrico
```

output:

```
ocirne
olleh
```

To do this, I can simply `tac` a file and pipe the output to `rev` (or the other way around), so one function that does the job is just this:

```bsh
revtac() { tac "$@" | rev; }
```

Is there a built-in function for the job?

I suspect that this could potentially break something, as it would reverse `<CR>` and `<LF>` on Windows-generated files, but I'm still interested.

Comment: Chaining two or more tools that do their respective things well is totally in the gist of the Unix philosophy. There is no point in maintaining a single tool that does what you want, because it's easy to build it with simpler tools, ad-hoc. And you just did.

Comment: `rev` already breaks CRLF line endings.

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski: And why would anyone think such a tool would be of enough value to include in a distribution?  If for some reason I had to do that, I'd write a simple C program, which I could probably do much faster than posting a question and waiting for an answer.

Comment: True. In fact old-school  'nix users would find that looking for a tool that does what two simple tools chained together do very well goes *against* the philosophy of the Unix toolbox, unless warranted by circumstance demanding a custom write.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no builtin function for the job.

BTW, neither `tac` nor `rev` are builtins. They are external binary programs, some *nix systems even come without them.

You can also use Perl to simulate the combo:

```
perl -lne 'push @lines, scalar reverse; END { print for reverse @lines }' -- file
```

Comment: Ok, it's clear I asked for builtins thinking that `tac` and `rev` where two builtins. What I meant is "something that I can find in `bash`", but you also specified that those two might not be provided on some systems.

Answer (score 3):

you can work around with a awk or sed script depending on your real needs
for example :

```
sed '/\n/!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//' /path/YOURFILE | sed '1!G;h;$!d'
```

I tested it in that way :

```
$ cat /tmp/a
hello
enrico
$ sed '/\n/!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//' /tmp/a | sed '1!G;h;$!d'
ocirne
olleh
$
```

Comment: Nice, I like sed, but since it is essentially also doing the 2 step work that can be done with `rev` and `tac`, I guess there's little point in using it instead of those two. But I'll really take time to look a bit more into the first command ;)

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis The point is portability. `sed` is found on any POSIX-compliant system (or that at least tries to comply), while `rev` and `tac` aren't among the [standard utilities](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html) (This does not mean that they _can't_ be found on non-GNU/Linux systems, though).

Answer (score 2):

Or awk:

```
awk '
  function rev(s,   t,i) {
    for (i = length(s); i > 0; i--)
      t = t substr(s, i, 1)
    return t
  }
  { line[NR] = rev($0) }
  END { for (i = NR; i > 0; i--) print line[i] }
' file
```